# Inverse Laplace transform of a multiplication of a constant matrix and an exponential matrix

Tags: matrices, laplace-transform, matrix-exponential, inverse-problems

Let $\mathcal{L}^{−1}\{⋅\}(z)$ be an inverse Laplace transform. Let $A, B$ be square matrixes, $I$ an identity matrix, and $\hat{\Phi}_z = \mathcal{L}\{\Phi(t)\}(z)$.

I have: $\hat{\Phi}_z = A[Iz - B]^{-1}$.

$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{[Iz - B]^{-1}\}(z) = e^{Bt}$ by the properties of matrix exponential and  by convolution theorem: $\mathcal{L}\{(f\star g)(t)\}(z) = F(z)G(z)$, what result can I get for $\Phi(t)$?

Is it $\Phi(t) = Ae^{Bt}$?

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$\hat{\Phi}_z = \mathcal{L}\{\Phi(t)\}(z) = A[Iz - B]^{-1}$$
But $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{[Iz - B]^{-1}\}(z) = e^{Bt}$ or $[Iz - B]^{-1}= \mathcal{L}\{ e^{Bt} \}$ so
$$\mathcal{L}\{\Phi(t)\}(z) = A\mathcal{L}\{ e^{Bt} \}$$ 
But since $A$ is independent of $z$, we have that
$$\mathcal{L}\{\Phi(t)\}(z) = \mathcal{L}\{ Ae^{Bt} \}$$ 
Applying inverse-Laplace on both sides
$$\Phi(t) =  Ae^{Bt} $$

Comment: This is surely true if A is a constant. I wonder if this remains true in the case A is a constant matrix (matrix with elements are constant)?

Comment: the thing is you did not mention that $A = A(t)$

Comment: No, I mean A is not depend on t, A is a matrix with all elements are constant.

Comment: oh okay @HaiDangNGO .. Indeed, when $A  = A(t)$, this is not true,